# Find edge contour points of a cluster

Tags: algorithm, cluster-computing

Considered a scatter of points over a 2d space (black points):
[image]

How can the contour points be found (blue circles), such that the contour of the cluster (red line) could be drawn as in the figure?

Please provide your solution in c++ if possible, or in matlab (without any built in functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that [alpha shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) are suitable for your task (instead of convex hull).

There are some implementations of alpha shapes, for example, in CGAL library.   Also I see Matlab links in search request.